# .getText().toString() returns null

Tags: java

I don't know if this was asked before but as I'm not finding anything useful I answer this by myself.

I'm trying to send data from one activity to another using a text view and by clicking an image button.
Everything works fine except for that it shows "null" where the TextView value should be.

Here is my code:

```
   // Main activity:
   btnsig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nombre = texto1.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });


    // ListenerActivity:
    texto2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto2);
    Typeface fuente = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/typing.ttf");
    texto2.setTypeface(fuente);
    texto2.setText("Encantado de conocerte " + nombre + ".Espero te guste el juego");
```

The variable `nombre` is public.

Any help?

Comment: Did you initialize texto1 properly?

Comment: texto1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto); and the other textview's name is texto2

Comment: I've removed "solved" from your question.  If you've answered your question, feel encouraged to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide more information. the only reason it would return null is because texto1 hasn't been set/initialized and you're trying to grab the text from the field but it's empty(null). Set "texto1". Unless you meant to get text from texto2 than change

```
texto1.getText()
```

to

```
texto2.getText()
```

Comment: texto1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto); doesnt this mean texto1 is initialized? because I have that in my oncreate method. And I want to take information from texto1  and send it to texto2

Comment: ah sorry thats why I asked you to post more code. not really sure what your doing but u can try doing?     texto1 = ((TextView)v).getText().toString());

Comment: tried it and when clicking the button for goin to the another activity it exits the app :s